# SceneKit background too bright when applying camera frame MTLTexture as a background

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, metal

[image: Washed out SceneKit texture]

I'm trying to convert a camera frame to a MTLTexture and then use it as a SceneKit background.  The texture is created successfully, and looks like it should when inspecting it.  However, when I set the following:

```
scene.background.contents = texture
```

It appears too bright / washed out.  Any ideas how to fix this?

Update 1:  Gist [here](https://gist.github.com/hartwoolery/aa65ffa4de79f612841e7e822aae1311)

Comment: you should post the code demonstrating how the `MTLTexture` is built.

Comment: @mnuages see gist in update.  As mentioned, texture renders correctly when inspected, but not when rendered to SceneKit. It's essentially the same code as the default metal-based ARKit project, except I pass the camera frame from the AVCaptureSession, and I'm using SceneKit instead of an MTKView

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out what was causing the washed out effect in the texture was the pixel format.  It should be .bgra8Unorm_srgb (not .bgra8Unorm).